# How to find all punctuation (both English and Chinese) using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.5

It seems that the Python3.5 `re` module doesn't support `\pP` (which works in Java and PHP), what should I do?

Comment: string.punctuation does not include chinese  punctuation

Comment: The [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module supports it, or there are other options on the dupe.

Comment: yes, i install regex module ,and it works .thanks